# Web Proxy software for Windows

Tags: proxy

I am thinking that I want to set up a web (http\https) proxy on a windows server 2003 machine.

My question is:

1) Can you configure windows server to do this?

2) If not then, any recommendations for the best software to do this?

Comment: I vote http://www.squid-cache.org/

Comment: moving this to SF would probably give better answers (i've voted to close for that reason- there's no need to repost this question there). I'd also ask if the proxy is meant to block sites, and do filtering, or just act as a proxy?

Comment: @The Journeyman geek - thanks, This is meant to act simply as a proxy. I find myself in a lot of different IT environments for my job, and essentially I want test sites when they are hit external to the network.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, Windows Server 2003 has IIS, which can be configured as a proxy.  Just use that.

Comment: I see a lot of info about setting up IIS as a reverse proxy, but I cannot find much information about setting it up a simple proxy. Is this just so simple that I am missing something?

Comment: Not sure if you can, I'm not aware of how. Microsoft wants you to buy ISA Server for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

What purpose of proxy setup?
In some cases FreeProxy can be useful.
In some cases squid for win32.